# Differentiate sessions in Magento

Tags: ajax, magento, session, authentication

I am having trouble, and I am sure that the answer is pretty simple, but I've yet to find it.  My issue:

I am building an AJAX login for Magento EE 1.9.1.1, and I have it completed, however it is not separating the `customer/session` and `core/session`.  It's not that big a deal except for the cart.  What's happening now is when customer is logged in, the item in the cart is transferred to the customer session as expected, however, on logout, the item stays in cart --  Then if I am to remove the item from the cart and re-login the item is missing from customer session.  Complete login code is as follows:

If it helps, I found this thread: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730057/magento-ajax-login-session-issues), but didn't understand it.

Simply put, I pass in username and password via POST to the following login.php

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));

if ($_POST['logout'] == "true"){
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->logout();
    echo "Logged out successfully!";
}

else {
/**
 * Login post action
 */

    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php");
    class Ns_Mylogin_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController{

    public function loginPostAction()
    {
        $result["error"]=0;

        $session = $this->_getSession();        

        if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
            try {
                $session->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
                if ($session->getCustomer()->getIsJustConfirmed()) {
                    $this->_welcomeCustomer($session->getCustomer(), true);

                }
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                switch ($e->getCode()) {
                    case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                        $result["error"]=1;
                        $message = Mage::helper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed. <a href="%s">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', Mage::helper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']));
                        break;
                    case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                        $result["error"]=1;
                        $message = $e->getMessage();
                        break;
                    default:
                        $result["error"]=1;
                        $message = $e->getMessage();
                }
                $session->setUsername($_POST['username']);

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // Mage::logException($e); // PA DSS violation: this exception log can disclose customer password
            }
            if(!$message || $message == '') {
                echo "Successful login!";
                }
            else{
                    echo $message;            
                    }            
        } 
        else {
            echo "Login and password are required!";
        }


}

}

$loginObject = new Ns_Mylogin_AccountController();
$loginObject->loginPostAction();
}
?>
```

As I mentioned, the login/logout works GREAT, it's  just not treating the sessions correctly as far as the cart is concerned.  Any help getting these sessions separated would be greatly appreciated!